# How can I request the latitude and longitude data from SnapToRoads API?

Tags: java, python, json, http, gps

Okay no so my code... which is already written, uses standard deviation and curve smoothing for the velocity and distance values of the GPS points. I need to send a request to SnapToRoads and get a set of values which are displayed on the API key link.
 I then want to get the intersection of values of points in range from all three methods: Standard deviation, Curve smoothing, and the API

I have no idea how to make an HTTP request, less get it in the tuple formate |Lat, Long|. Sample data from the API page:

{
  "snappedPoints": [

```
{
  "location": {
    "latitude": 12.919082345679861,
    "longitude": 77.651684714045615
  },
  "originalIndex": 0,
  "placeId": "ChIJ6yP7JIIUrjsRpHSPhEcWRHc"
},
{
  "location": {
    "latitude": 12.918915069015311,
    "longitude": 77.651690053806533
  },
  "originalIndex": 1,
  "placeId": "ChIJ6yP7JIIUrjsRpHSPhEcWRHc"
},
{
```

]

Thank you

Comment: use urllib or requests module

Answer (score 0):

Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) 
comes in handy for this kind of work.

but after you download and install requests
you basically do

```
import requests
list_of_coordinates = []
api_request = requests.get(url_to_api_endpoint)
if (api_request.status_code == 200): #verifying the request was successful
      data = api_request.json() #converts it to json/dictionary so you can key in
      #note that the json returned seems to be a dictionary that contains a list
      location_points = data['snappedPoints'] #get the list of location objects
      for coord_vals in data_points:
          coordinates =  (location_points['location']['longitude'], location_points['location']['latitude'])
          list_of_coordinates.append(coordinates)
```